# Couch Db - indexing and searching

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, couchdb, bigdata, nosql

I am new to couch db. Just seeking for explanations regarding the indexing methodologies that can be used in couch db/Big Couch/(or any other clustered NoSQL database) for effective full-text search. Out of Just Lucene, Elastic Search, Solr - what would be the most advantageous methodology that shall be used for searching in terms of full-text search for huge terabytes of data? And the reason behind it?

Also, on googling I realised that couch db is unclustered. Eventually BigCouch was founded which was clustered database. Are there any better database techniques for ensuring cluster management with huge terabytes of data??